# Samsung Galaxy 4 (and above) - Native Browser - Bottom toolbar height and behavior?

Tags: javascript, android, native, samsung-mobile, galaxy

I have run into an inner height issue on a Samsung Galaxy 4. It ignores this height on its native browser.

The window.innerHeight property returns the height with the bottom toolbar on an iPhone.

Is there a way of getting this height for the Samsung Galaxy?

Other Samsung phones are fine because they use an older version of the native browser. The Galaxy uses its own.

**EXTRA:**

I would also like to know the behavior of the toolbar. It starts to show when the user scrolls up.

How many pixels do you have to scroll before it decides to stay on the screen?

I have noticed it will disappear if you have not scrolled further than half its height.

Cheers!